# Writing an Android lock screen replacement?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm looking to write an application which allows an alternative lock screen for Android. I've seen posts around here on SO as well as applications in the Play Store, but I can't seem to find any APIs for doing it on developer.android.com.

How do you write a replacement lock screen for Android?

Comment: On developer.android.com, you'll only be able to find apis for the lockscreen for Android 4.0 and above (I believe). Anything below that, and the lock screen app developers have navigated a maze of undocumented apis

Comment: Can you link me to any content that would explain how to setup permissions etc? I'm looking for a starting point that I can't seem to find.

Comment: My mistake, it was Android 4.2 and above. See http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen Note that HTC also has its own lockscreen api, and Qualcomm may as well, on Android 4.x and above.

Comment: All that is documented there is lock screen widgets. Is that the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they're not a complete replacement of the lock screen, but lock screen widgets allow you to customize the lock screen. Also, check out the Dreams section, Dreams are an other form of lock screen customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize what others have said on here and what similar questions have asked:

**TL;DR No, you cannot easily write a replacement for Android's lock screen.**

The longer version: In order to write a lock screen replacement, you'd need to either create a custom ROM which bundles your lockscreen or you'd need to wade through undocumented Android and device-specific APIs to work around this problem. Here's hoping that Android M will allow us to write lock-screen replacements.